# Click on the button after the class appears in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a form in the popup window that sends data to Ajax. After a successful form, a message about successful submission with the `.form-message--success` class appears below. I would like that when this class appears in 5 seconds, the window close button with the id `#close_pop a` is clicked.

Is this possible when a class is added dynamically to the DOM?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work(

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.jet-form-message--success').on(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#close_pop a').click();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This checks the DOM when the document is "ready". You need to attach an eventListener to the DOM and check if this element ever appears. But this is not the most efficient  way to do it (probably the least efficient). You should move the logic after the trigger (after the api request)

Comment: Not, not possible. Does the ajax call, modal fire any events when it loads?

Comment: Do you have access to the code that performs the Ajax request? Can you attach it to your question?

Comment: @epascarello Honestly, I don't know. Didn't check it.

Comment: @TasosBu This is a form from jetengine forms. I don't know how to pass this code here(

Comment: Wrong link, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#user-form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "form.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $( this ).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert('form send success');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#close_pop a').click();
                }, 2000);
           },
         error: function(xr) {
            alert("error "+xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText);
        }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The tricky part here seems to be, that there is no access to the ajax code itself and that you would need an outside observer to detect that the form was successfuly sent.